# Not found when adding a new controller to a default Symfony app with Apache

Tags: apache, symfony, http-status-code-404

I've created a virtual host on a virtual machine, setup using vagrant. Now I set the `DocumentRoot` of the virtual host to be the `web` directory of the symfony installation. I added a new controller, which is the following:

```
/*
@Route("/contact")
*/
public function contactAction(Request $request)
{
    // replace this example code with whatever you need
    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
        'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..'),
    ]);
}
```

to the `DefaultController.php` file, but when I go to `ServerName/contact`, but it returns a 404 page.

I've tried to do `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`, but this only introduced new problems, which I solved by recreating the app...

**Edit**

I see this page:

[image]

Comment: Do you see the apache 404 or the Symfony one? Anyway, did you [configure the apache properly](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html)?

Comment: @kero How can I see it?

Comment: Looks like apache's error message (the symfony one is more styled ;). Please follow the manual (link in my first comment), you either need to set `AllowOverride` (so the .htaccess inside /web works), or place the proper code in your vHost in addition to `DocumentRoot`

Comment: @kero - not necessarily. When you get 404/500 in `prod` environment, you won't see the styled one. This is most likely, him, trying to open the page in `prod` environment. If that's the case, try switching to `dev` instead and see what's going on.

Comment: In production environment, the cache does never clear automatically. You said `cache:clear --env=prod` brings more problem, but does it works with dev environnement at all? what are does production problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.tld
ServerAlias www.domain.tld

DocumentRoot /var/www/project/web
<Directory /var/www/project/web>
    # enable the .htaccess rewrites
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Personal gist for apache settings :)

Don't forget to restart/reload apache2 afterwards